# How can Brook see and hear without organs?

Tags: one-piece

How is it possible that his five senses are still working?
How can he even talk?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**In short it is because of the Yomi Yomi no Mi Fruit's power he is able see, taste and do other things.**

According to [wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Yomi_Yomi_no_Mi):

> Through the fruit's powers, Brook is able to function without the
>   presence of necessary and vital body parts that have decomposed long
>   ago. He is able to interact with the environment around him without
>   the presence of eye balls or any other sensory organ to aid him. He,
>   in particular, retains his ability of speech despite his vocal chords
>   and even his windpipe have long since rotted away. He is able to taste
>   and digest food like any other normal living thing to sustain himself.
>   Drinking milk in particular heals him as the calcium intake repairs
>   any of Brook's bones that may have been broken in battle. Depending on
>   the situation, Brook is also able to produce organic matter such as
>   tears, fecal matter, and even blood from his nose despite not having
>   any organs nor bodily liquids to produce such matter.

Comment: In other words.....a character made to be creepy